# Create Muti Page PDF Document from One Page Document

Tags: itext, itext7

I'm using iText7 for .NET c#.  I'm trying to create a multi page PDF document (*n-number of page*s) in memory where the source pdf document consists of only **one** page.

I can create a new document with the one page, but unable to create the additional pages as needed. I've tried

```
MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();    
Stream s1 = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetManifestResourceStream("doc.pdf");    
s1.CopyTo(ms)

PdfReader readerSrc = new PdfReader(ms);
PdfDocument srcPdfDoc = new PdfDocument(readerSrc);
MemoryStream msDest = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
PdfDocument destPdfDoc - new PdfDocument(new PdfWriter(msDest));

srcPdfDoc.CopyPageTo(1,1,destPdfDoc)
destPdfDoc.AddNewPage(1, new PageSize.A4)
srcPdfDoc.CopyPageTo(1,2,destPdfDoc)
```

But then I get an ArgumentOutOfRange exception...Index out of range...etc....

I've tried closing the destPdfDoc to then re-open it thinking that the second page hadn't been written until I close it. But then when open the destPdfDoc up the 2nd time, it has no pages. I can't figure out how to open up the destPdfDoc in like "Append" mode. If that makes sense. Bottom line, I'm lost.

I've done this using iTextSharp, but then when using the new iText7, the library changed and my old code doesn't work anymore.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.

```
MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();    
Stream s1 = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetManifestResourceStream("doc.pdf");    
s1.CopyTo(ms)

PdfReader readerSrc = new PdfReader(ms);
PdfDocument srcPdfDoc = new PdfDocument(readerSrc);
MemoryStream msDest = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
PdfDocument destPdfDoc - new PdfDocument(new PdfWriter(msDest));


PdfMerger merger = new PdfMeger(destPdfDoc);
merger.Merge(srcPdfDoc , 1,1)
merger.Merge(srcPdfDoc , 1,1)

destPdfDoc.Close();
srcPdfDoc.Close();
```

Comment: After working with this further, I realized the form fields did not transfer over. The structure isn't correct, which basically renders this useless. So back to square one.